# How get per core cpu usage on Android / Galaxy SIII

Tags: android, linux, galaxy

I've a Samsung Galaxy SIII with Android 4.1.2 "rooted". I need to measure the CPU usage for some multithreaded applications I've written in C/C++, however I need this information in a per core basis.

I know (due wikipedia, ...) that the Galaxy has a SoC with 4 ARM Cortex A9 however when I do a `cat /proc/cpuinfo` it doesn't show any information regarding the number of available cores (as usual in any Linux), is this correct behavior?

I've read somewhere that I can use `cat /proc/stat` to see the per core load average however, in my device, the content of such "file" only shows information for the "core0", again, is this correct or do I need to do something to enable all cores?

I also tried with `top` and `ps` without success.

```
EDITED:
----------------- cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 0 (v7l)
processor   : 0
BogoMIPS    : 1592.52

Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x3
CPU part    : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 0

Chip revision   : 0011
Hardware    : SMDK4x12
Revision    : 000c
Serial      : 11e16f694df1267e


----------------- cat /proc/stat

cpu  89515 1686 23283 464122 3835 2 376 0 0 0
cpu0 74214 457 16736 221609 1111 1 347 0 0 0
intr 1860068 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 .... (removed: a serie of numbers)
ctxt 3138146
btime 1371578546
processes 15904
procs_running 1
procs_blocked 0
softirq 1154788 12 403499 864 4501 12 12 444746 67202 576 233364
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get information about the number of cores by examining the hotplug devices, `/sys/devices/system/cpu/present` and `/sys/devices/system/cpu/possible`.  See also [the hotplug docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-hotplug.txt).

I'm not sure this helps you much as far as getting CPU usage.  You can get a crude sense for how much user and system time a thread has used from `adb shell ps -x -t`, e.g.:

```
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
system    19598 19574 955672 57324 ffffffff 4012d9b8 S system_server (u:2186, s:1521)
system    19602 19598 955672 57324 c007f840 4012db84 S GC (u:79, s:6)
```

This says that system_server's main thread has used 2186 ticks of user time, while the GC thread has used 79 ticks.

If you can instrument your application, you can use the POSIX `clock_gettime()` call with `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` to measure the amount of CPU time used by a given thread.  (The Dalvik VM uses this when generating results for traceview.)

This is all per-thread, however.  Getting per-core usage information is much harder, especially on Android:

- The hotplug mechanism can add or remove cores during your test.
- The kernel can adjust the CPU frequency of each core individually, so doing X amount of work may take different amounts of time on different cores.
- Threads can migrate between cores (by default there is no core affinity).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. So Android can turn on/off the cores at any given time? Can you give any document to support this? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... I don't know if formal documentation exists on this.  It's done to improve battery life.  You should be able to observe it for yourself by watching the CPU status entries and supplying various loads to the system.  A multi-thread CPU load program may be useful here to keep the cores awake (e.g. http://bigflake.com/cpu-spinner.c.txt or http://bigflake.com/MultiCore.java.txt).  The details vary for different devices and different revs of Android.

Comment: @JohnTortugo: "Can you give any document to support this?" -- http://www.nvidia.com/object/tegra-3-processor.html ("NVIDIA's innovative Variable SMP architecture (PDF 919 KB) enables four performance cores to be used for max burst, when needed, with each core independently and automatically enabled and disabled based on workload. The single battery-saver core (or companion core) handles low-power tasks like active standby, music, and video, and is transparent to the OS and applications.").

Comment: @JohnTortugo: "Can you give any document to support this?" -- http://www.extremetech.com/computing/99721-how-snapdragon-s4-and-tegra-3-manage-arm-cores-differently ("To implement aSMP, the new Snapdragons will have a dedicated voltage plane and clock frequency for each core. As the demands on a system change, the SoC can alter the power of each core to find the most efficient voltage and speed, even going so far as to completely shut off some cores.") Plenty more material on this on the Internet, accessible via search engines.

Answer (score 0):

It should include the different cores (showing Nexus 7):

```
$ adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 9 (v7l)
processor   : 0
BogoMIPS    : 1993.93

processor   : 1
BogoMIPS    : 1993.93

processor   : 2
BogoMIPS    : 1993.93

processor   : 3
BogoMIPS    : 1993.93
```

and stat:

```
$ adb shell cat /proc/stat
cpu  1623573 112801 907626 32541158 125987 68 5952 0 0 0
cpu0 804181 45734 569092 7373416 43990 49 4990 0 0 0
cpu1 332438 26759 142892 8311267 31256 9 574 0 0 0
cpu2 332889 25551 130711 8319093 30900 7 218 0 0 0
cpu3 154065 14757 64931 8537382 19841 3 170 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a core is Online/offline by reading the file

/sys/devices/system/cpu/CPUx/online  (x is the number of the core and in Samsung S3: 0,1,2,3)

if it is "0" , the core is Offline and if it is "1" the core is online. Now, you can use /proc/stat to calculate CPU Usage but for Samsung S3 it will only show the cores which are active at the time you read /proc/stat. Now, to calculate CPU Usage for all the cores, you have to force all the cores online. You can use **System Tuner App** available at Play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.pmw&hl=en for forcing all the cores online. Install the app and then put the cores online by ( CPU -> Boot settings -> Force all CPUs online -> On boot Completed ), now you can reboot your device and all the cores are online. Now read **/proc/stat** and calculate CPU Usage for all the cores. If you need more explanation about **/proc/stat** http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/procstat.htm
 can help.

I noticed that load gets distributed among all the active cores (must be some system processes), I was running Skype over Wifi and without forcing all the cores online it was using 2 cores: core 0 and core 1 at 30% and 25% respectively. I measured the CPU Usage again for the same use case(Skype over wifi) after forcing all the cores online and I noticed that load was distributed among all active cores ( Core1: 26% , Core 2: 9%, Core 3: 11%, Core 4: 10% ).